# Unable To Install SQL Server 2008 On Windows 7 & Windows XP

Tags: windows, installation, .net-framework, sql-server-2008

For the last five hours I've been trying to install Microsoft SQL Server 2008, first on Windows 7 and then Windows XP. Both have had the same issue. Even before the installation starts, an error message appears saying:

> Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installation has failed. SQL Server 2008 Setup requires .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 to be installed.

I have installed **everything** in the hope of getting past this. the service pack it refers to has even been installed and I can see them in the control panel!

I have installed Framework 2.0, Framework 2.0 SP1, Framework 3.5, Framework 3.5 SP1, Windows Installer 3.5 and Windows Installer 4.0. Even installed the Service Pack for SQL Server 2008.... But, nothing, works!

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong or what could be wrong? I'm seriously close to the end of my tether, I've even sent Steve Ballmer an email with my frustration. I would seriously appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Do you have any previous version of sql serve installed ? or visual studio ?

Comment: Not on the XP machine. That's a complete reinstall. On the Windows 7 machine I have VS 2010 installed, and had SQL 2008 Express but I removed that with no joy.

Comment: On the Windows 7 machine, you cannot install SQL Server after Visual Studio. See if that's the problem with that machine. Alternatively, your installation media may be damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Remove all copies of the .NET Framework with [this tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301085724/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx).

Step 2: Reboot the computer.

Step 3: Reinstall the .NET Framework from v1.1, v2.0, v3.0 to v3.5, but *reboot* in between each version, and run Windows Updates each time to make sure they're all up to date (may take several reboots).

Step 4. Install SQL Server.

Comment: On the XP machine I tried to uninstall v2.0 but it refused. It gave an error (I don't know what it was at the moment as I'm not at home now). I will try your answer when I get home. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, this tool will fix that for you.

Comment: I've followed all the above steps and its still the same. What's even weirder, I have tried to install SQL Server 2008 Express and this has installed fine.

Comment: See my response above.